# How to get value from cookie/service in app-routing module

Tags: angular

I have angular site www.domainname.com with app-routing.module and those Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "homepage/:lang/:country",
    ...
  },  
  ...
  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "/homepage/en/gb",
    pathMatch: "full"
  },
]
```

If you access the page via www.domainname.com, you will be redirected to www.domainname.com/homepage/en/gb page. I will store your language preference to cookie as well as to LocaleService in angular-l10n package.

Let's say you change your language to zh-cn and it will be stored accordingly in the locale service and cookie.

If you visit next time www.domainname.com, how can I tell the app-routing module to use the lang/country value from cookie/locale service and not to redirect to the default en/gb page?

Comment: what about using a router guard to get cookie and redirect， it is not posible to inject a service in to module ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngx cookie service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service) to set cookie lets say cookie name language.

On your app component on router.changes.subscribe event you can check cookie using simple cookie service get method and check which path to redirect using data in cookie using router.navigate()

Answer (score 1):

So you have route like;

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "homepage/:lang/:country",
        ...
    },  
    ...
    {
        path: "**",
        redirectTo: "/homepage/en/gb",
        pathMatch: "full"
    }
]
```

Now as per your problem, I would do a simple change to solve it.

```
{
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "/index",
    pathMatch: "full"
}
```

Now in index page I would write code for;

```
Check localStorage if there is any language preference
     If found 
        redirect to "homepage/:lang/:country"
     else 
        redirect to "/homepage/en/gb"
```

In this approach you will get another benefit also, like if you need to check some other things also later on based on requirement you can add additional logic here.

But if I understand correctly, your necessity is that after user select a language, from next time you like to open that language specific page from next time onward. But the process you are following will be browser specific, hope you have already thought about it.